# android studio: SnackBar is beneath visable screen

Tags: android-studio

i am having trouble with the Snackbar. I recently moved to Kotlin, Electric Eel and Material design 3. So it is a problem to pinpoint the source of the problem.
So in my main activity i have this XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/barLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dummy" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then in my Kotlin MainActivity.kt i do this:

```
   fun deleteItem(position: Int) {
    val lDeletedItem = mAdapter.removeItem(position) ?: return

    val message = Snackbar.make(binding.rootContainer, R.string.DialogDeleteTripMessage, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    message.setAction(R.string.DialogDeleteTripButton) { view ->
        mAdapter.addItem(position,
                         lDeletedItem
        )
    }
    message.setActionTextColor(Convertor.ResourceToColorInt(this, R.attr.colorSnackBarAction))
    message.addCallback(object : Snackbar.Callback() {
        override fun onDismissed(transientBottomBar: Snackbar, event: Int) {
            if (event == DISMISS_EVENT_TIMEOUT) {
                mViewModel.deleteItem(lDeletedItem.id)
            }
        }
    })
    message.show()
}
```

Everything works just fine but the Snackbar is display outside the visible screen:
[image]

Anybody an idea? did the same thing before and then is was working but changed so many things that i am lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
Might not be the perfect solution but still...

I added a second contrainLayout between the rootContainer and the AppBarLayout
made it 200dp height and constraint it to the bottom of the parent.

The below the "val message = ...." line i added:  *message.anchorView = binding.snackBarContainer*

Apperently when you set the anchor it links to the top of that view and not the bottom which result the snackbar to be shown at a nice height.